# Get rid of default "search" entry in "/etc/resolv.conf" on Amazon EC2 Fedora instance

Tags: dhclient

Case of an Amazon EC2 Fedora 23 instance.

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` which determines how DNS lookups are performed by glibc resolver (see `man resolv`), looks as follows:

```
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
search eu-west-1.compute.internal club
nameserver 172.31.0.2
```

- The `nameserver 172.31.0.2` line points to the EC2-provided "DNS cache" on my private virtual local network, which is fine.
- The `search` line is bothersome because it instructs the resolver to try to resolve `X.eu-west-1.compute.internal` and `X.club` when it is being asked to resolve `X`. The `eu-west-1.compute.internal` domain comes from the fact that this is the suffix of the internally-used hostname: Looking up anything in that domain is pointless. The `club` domain comes from the fact that this is the suffix of the externally-used hostname: Looking up anything in that domain is pointless and possibly a security problem.

So I want to get rid of the `search` line.

Doing this elegantly apparently demands that I tell `/usr/sbin/dhclient-script` (see `man dhclient-script`) to not set it up in the first place.

A look at said script shows that I might modify it and comment out the bash function `eventually_add_hostnames_domain_to_search` or the calls to it, but is there a better way (some configuration option somewhere)?

Answer (score 1):

you can set `PEERDNS=no` in the relevant `/etc/syscofig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` file which will stop  dhclient from changing /etc/resolv.conf.

Once you've done that you can configure /etc/resolv.conf however you like.

Comment: But what if amazon decides to change the nameserver's IP address?

Comment: Configure name servers that are unlikely to change 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 and others.